# Access Json in Drive via Apps Script HTML Service to create Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-apps-script

I am trying to use Google App script's html service and Maps API V3 to create a map.

I can get the google base map working, but I would like to load a geojson in Google Drive as a data layer on the map and am running into issues. I am working in an unbound script editor.

here is my Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ui')
                    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)  
}
function getData(){
  return DriveApp.getFileById("/*file-id*/")
}
```

and here is my ui.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Data Layer: Simple</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key/*my key*/&callback=initMap">
    </script>

    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
       map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 11,
          center: {lat: 29.454235, lng: -98.506203}
        });
        var x = google.script.run.getData() //call app script function to get geojson file here
        map.data.loadGeoJson(x); //load geojson as data layer
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The results of this script is a blank google map where I would expect there to be some polygons loaded on the map like Google's data layer example https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-simple

Should I be using app script scriplets instead of google.script.run? I was having trouble getting that to work either.

Any help or insight would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the line of code

```
var x = google.script.run.getData()
```

is an async call so the data is loaded after the map is rendered and it's never showed. A solution to your problem should be using template (but I don't think it's the nicest solution. A nice solution is to handle the async call) nevertheless here is what you need to change:

In your GS file instead of invoking a html file invoke a html template:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(filename)('ui').evaluate()
                    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)  
}
```

in your UI file replace the line `var x = google.script.run.getData()` by:

```
var x =  "<?!= DriveApp.getFileById("/*file-id*/").getBlob().getDataAsString() ?>"
```

`DriveApp.getFileById` will only catch the file but it's not readable as it. You then need to say that you want to get the content of the file using `getBlob().getDataAsString()`.
the marker `<?!=` and `?>` are here to say that in this template file we need to evaluate the code inside before rendering it.

Comment: Thanks Harold.  That was a helpful explanation and I think that puts me on the right track.  When I run the script now, I get a      "userCodeAppPanel:8 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" error and a `code "Uncaught InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function" code`  However I can print the variable x to console.log so I know the geojson string is being pulled correctly. Seems

Comment: Ok. got it working.  Just had to tweak a few things. For reference, I removed "(filename)" from `return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(filename)('ui').evaluate()`  removed outside quotations from `"<?!= DriveApp.getFileById("/*file-id*/").getBlob().getDataAsString() ?>"`  used `map.data.addGeoJson` instead of `map.data.loadGeoJson` after these changes everything worked as expected. Thanks Harold!